# Problems upgrading 14.04 to 16.04

Tags: upgrade, transfer

I've been trying to upgrade from my current 14.04 Ubuntu to the newest version, however I'm getting the error for no space in `/boot`. I have a 4 TB solid state drive, however I think that Ubuntu was loaded onto the general computer memory drive. I was hoping you could help me, or direct me to a link that would help, transfer Ubuntu onto the solid state, in such a way that I would not have to completely erase everything and start over again, and I would have more than enough space to deal with any future upgrades.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this will show what is consuming space on /boot

```
du -k /boot
```

issue this command to delete old unused kernel releases which will free up space on /boot

```
dpkg -l linux-{image,headers}-"[0-9]*" | awk '/^ii/{ print $2}' | grep -v -e `uname -r | cut -f1,2 -d"-"` | grep -e '[0-9]' | xargs sudo apt-get -y purge
```